# Calculate max, min and mean values of element in an array

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following arrays:

```
x = [0.01067573 0.0139049  0.01713406 0.01902214 0.02228745 0.0243896
 0.02575684 0.0281498  0.0303585  0.03053122 0.0282564  0.03066194
 0.0318088  0.03290647 0.03438853 0.03613471 0.0383046  0.0365982
 0.0348341  0.0289057  0.0122935  0.01067573 0.01067573 0.01067573
 0.01067573 0.01067573 0.01067573 0.01067573 0.01067573 0.01067212
 0.01046571]
y=[0.01067573 0.0139049  0.01713406 0.01994051 0.02141184 0.0238336
 0.02698133 0.0296072  0.0320376  0.0291436  0.0262487  0.0279379
 0.0294417  0.0308968  0.0323344  0.0337727  0.0336187  0.0357771
 0.0340007  0.0282703  0.0123555  0.01095551 0.01067573 0.01083439
 0.01067573 0.01067573 0.01075694 0.01095551 0.01067573 0.01076594
 0.01098551]
z=[0.01067573 0.0139049  0.01713406 0.0188497  0.0213636  0.0248497
 0.0252536  0.0274743  0.0295116  0.0274806  0.0273424  0.02900906
 0.03005469 0.0308758  0.03167363 0.03314961 0.03595196 0.0375954
 0.03869676 0.02937896 0.012627   0.01067573 0.01067573 0.01098724
 0.01154837 0.01080896 0.01085163 0.01139469 0.01067573 0.01076688
 0.01068204]
```

I want to calculate the maximum, minimum, and mean value of each element in these arrays, but I return one array of each attribute with respect of the length of the array. For example,

```
max = [0.01067573 0.0139049  0.01713406 0.01994765 0.02185929 0.02423337
 0.02760071 0.0296107  0.0316786  0.0289268  0.0285128  0.03066194
 0.0313552  0.03287471 0.03449902 0.03616078 0.0368397  0.0406049
 0.035475   0.03232031 0.0124145  0.01067573 0.01067573 0.01100561
 0.01067573 0.01067573 0.01085745 0.01067573 0.01067573 0.01071802
 0.01072735]
```

Is there any way?

Comment: How do you mean, you want the mean, max and min of every value? Do you mean from the entire arrays?

Comment: @bilalj mean value np.mean(). Let's say from element 0 in each array x,y,z, I calculate the average value, as well as the max and min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
a = np.vstack((x, y, z))

max1 = np.max(a, axis=0)
avg1 = np.mean(a, axis=0)
min1 = np.min(a, axis=0)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use selection sort algorithm to get elements in ascending order(min) or descending order(max)